# Empty project creating by QT Creator + cmake doesn't work

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I create empty C++ project in QT Creator using cmake. After some menus where I choose "cmake" as a building tool I see a project hierarchy:

```
- MyTestCMake2
    - CMakeLists.txt
```

(New Project -> Non-Qt Project -> Plain C++ Application -> checked CMake for building system)

And that's all! It's strange but QTCreator opens main.cpp with some C++ code but QTCreator tells me that this file does not a part of my project. I try to add main.cpp manually to MyTestCMake2 project but I can't do it. It's disabled.

CMakeLists.txt content is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyTestCMake2)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

I try to run cmake with: **Build -> Run CMake** but nothing happens. What's wrong? Why QTCreator doesn't work with CMake properly?

My env is:

```
cmake: 3.9.1
Qt Creator: 4.3.1 (Qt: 5.9.1)
Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5
```

**SOLVED**
I've upgraded Qt Creator to 4.4 and it worked out of the box! I did the same steps as before but now it works without any problems! What a magic.

Comment: I have experienced that only Console applications work. What kind of project are you creating and which version of Qt, CMake?

Comment: A simple test case works for me on Fedora 26 with QtCreator and CMake installed. I did: "New Project", "Non-Qt Project", "Plain C++ Application", and "CMake" under Build System.

Comment: @JensMunk, cmake: 3.9.1, Qt Creator: 4.3.1, Qt: 5.9.1, Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: I have the same issue with almost empty Projects pane: Qt `5.12.6`, Qt Creator `4.10.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded Qt Creator to 4.4 and it worked out of the box! I did the same steps as before but now it works without any problems! What a magic.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the mixed QT 5.x installation breaks the kits. Several kits starts to show a warning in the kit popup message balloon (Tools->Options->Kits->Kits: Auto-detected/Manual) about unsupported generator cmake server mode (cmake `-E` command line option).

Seems only behind the cmake server mode the Qt Creator can properly build the Projects pane.

The only way I could get it fixed is complete QT uninstall before install. Even the last QT 5.x minor version can break the kits (5.12.12 at the moment).